# Converting dataframe to dictionary with values that have an n*n structure

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table in the database that looks like so

```
| day | x | y | value |
|---------------------|
| 0   | 0 | 1 |   20  |
| 0   | 1 | 2 |   20  |
| 0   | 3 | 3 |   20  |
| 1   | 0 | 0 |   20  |
| 1   | 0 | 3 |   20  |
| 1   | 2 | 2 |   20  |
| 1   | 3 | 1 |   20  |
| 1   | 3 | 3 |   20  |
| 2   | 2 | 1 |   20  |
| 2   | 2 | 2 |   20  |
| 2   | 0 | 0 |   20  |
| 2   | 3 | 1 |   20  |
| 2   | 0 | 3 |   20  |
```

Basically this is sensor data over an area with fixed dimensions in this example 3*3 but the instrument doesn't cover the whole space.

I want to create an output that looks like this

```
{
  day0: {[[null, 20, null, 20], [null, 20, null, 20],[null, 20, null, 20],[null, 20, null, 20]]},
  day1: {[[null, 20, null, 20], [null, 20, null, 20],[null, 20, null, 20],[null, 1, null, 20]]},
  day2: {[[null, 20, null, 20], [null, 20, null, 20],[null, 20, null, 20],[null, 20, null, 20]]},
}
```

I currently achieve this by creating a 3*3 numpy matrix with all nulls then loop through the dataset filling the matrix up with the x and y values and then convert to a dictionary afterwards but I believe this is not efficient since it has an O(N) time complexity. I have tried to do it pandas pivot but with the duplicated index(days) this won't be possible. I would like to achieve this in a better way without looping with maybe pandas if possible.

Ps: this is mainly for plotting purposes in plotly.js as that is the format in which the api accepts plotting of heatmaps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for this problem lies with scipy's sparse matrix. I tried to use the coo_matrix this would have been the perfect fix but it is only available in 2d, however, If I filter out each day, then I can extract the x and y cordinates as a sparse matrix and then I reduce the loop to the number of days. Here is my implementation(maybe naive):

```
days = {}
for i in range(0, days + 1):
    x = df.loc[df['day'] == i, 'x'].values
    y = df.loc[df['day'] == i, 'y'].values
    v = df.loc[df['day'] == i, 'value'].values
    out = coo_matrix((v, (x,y)), shape=(3, 3)).toarray()
    days[f'days {i}'] = out
```

Using pythons timer module, the last block of code ran for approximately 0.6secs with 40k data points and compared to

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    x = 2
```

Which took about 7 secs. This is the best I can do at this moment to avoid a full loop over the data points.

Ps: you can achieve the same results with numpy.

```
days = {}
for i in range(0, days + 1):
    x = df.loc[df['day'] == i, 'x'].values
    y = df.loc[df['day'] == i, 'y'].values
    v = df.loc[df['day'] == i, 'value'].values
    out = np.zeros(3, 3)
    out[x, y] = v
    days[f'days {i}'] = out.tolist()
```